# Why this preg_match doesn't work

Tags: php, preg-match

I need valid numbers between 0.00000001 and 999.
I used preg_match:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,8})?$/',0.0000339);
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work.
If I write a number:
`0.0001` it work but `0.00001` or `0.0000001` it doesn't work and `0.11111111` returns true.
You can test http://writecodeonline.com/php/
Why?

Comment: Why don't you use a normal if statement like: `if ($number <= 999 && $number >= 0.00000001)` ?

Comment: Because you're not passing a string to preg_match, but letting PHP convert the literal float `0.0000339` into a string `3.39E-5`.

Comment: Or `$number < 1000 && $number > 0` if you are just trying to account for really small positive numbers...

Comment: I just deleted my post, it was only detecting if numeric but not if value is between 0.00000001 and 999. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

It work:

```
$number = 0.0000001; 
echo preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,8})?$/',"$number");
```